# Move cookie from a Website to Another

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

How Can I move a Cookie from a Website to Another? I'm using Laravel, and both sites are built with It.

Comment: no, you can't (from the server side) - for security reasons. You can though do it on the client side youself, manually; not via javascript - again for security reasons.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Why would you need that? Doesn't Laravel encrypt all cookies with a site specific key?

Comment: This question sounds _very_ interesting, but could use more details. I've worked in situations where a single piece of software running on a single server was operating on multiple domains and needed to link to the other domains for legacy-code related reasons. Is that the issue? Are you trying to migrate entire _sessions_? or just _cookies_ between origins? Are these websites running different instances of an application?